# Removing files based on MIME types in linux

Tags: grep, find, rm, mime-types

I'm quite a beginner to Linux and I'm having trouble removing files based on the mime type. Currently, I have a set of files on my Linux machine, and below are the types for a small subset.

```
0FiTahKc: M3U playlist, ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
0FJsEpTc: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
0fKPkmwe: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
0FLR6MWB: ASCII text
0FMa2xL2: C source, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
0fN8DDbf: exported SGML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
0fSM3YyG: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
0fTXKtZD: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
0FUcusxr: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

I tried looking into the different type of files in my directory and below is the output:

```
$ find -type f -exec file {} \; | sed 's/^.*: //' | sort -u

ASCII text
ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
ASCII text, with no line terminators
ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
C source, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
exported SGML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
M3U playlist, ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
M3U playlist, UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
```

I wanted to perform a grep of 'C source','M3U playlist' and 'SGML' etc or using 'find' and delete these files from the directory except the ASCII types in the first 5 lines. I'm looking for a command or a script that I can run where I can pipe different type of these file types and remove them.

Comment: The `file` command is telling you what kind of file it is, but this does not give you actual MIME types. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type

Answer (score 6):

Piece some tools together into a single line:

- Use `find` and `files` to list every file's mime type (as shown in your question).
- Use `awk` to filter that list based on the type.
- Use `xargs` to take that filtered list and `rm` each file.

**I recommend you use `echo` to prevent `rm` doing anything first.  This will dry-run the command so you can check which files it will remove!**

Eg: to remove "C source".

```
find . -type f -exec file {} + | awk -F: '$(NF) ~ "C source" {print $1}' | xargs echo rm
```

Then run the same line removing `echo` to actually remove the files.

---

To explain the use of awk for filtering, the clause `$(NF) ~ "C source"` tells awk to match any line with the second column (everything after a `:`) containing `C source`.  This condition can be extended to anything you like.  So most obviously you can search for `C Source` or `M3U playlist` using:

```
$(NF) ~ "C source" || $(NF) ~ "M3U playlist"
```

Example:

```
find . -type f -exec file {} + | awk -F: '$(NF) ~ "C source" || $2 ~ "M3U playlist" {print $1}' | xargs echo rm
```

Comment: Thanks philip I was able to remove C source files. How can I do the same for multiple keywords like for python source, C++ source in a single command?

Comment: @alex Edited, combine multiple clauses with `||` just make sure each clause starts with `$2 ~` meaning type matches the text.  See my edit.

Comment: @Quasímodo Interesting edge case.  I think mime types containing colons are less likely.  If colons on file names are a risk then `$(NF)` could be used in place of `$2`.  I've edited the answer to used NF since I think it's slightly safer.

Answer (score 4):

To delete all files where the `file` output starts with the filename and `:`  followed by `ASCII text` using `find` and a bash regex match:

```
find -type f -exec bash -c '
  for f; do
    file=$(file -- "$f")
    if [[ $file =~ ^$f:\ "ASCII text" ]]; then
      echo rm -- "$f"
    fi
  done
' bash {} +
```

Likewise for `C source`, `M3U playlist` or `exported SGML document`:

```
find -type f -exec bash -c '
  for f; do
    file=$(file -- "$f")
    if [[ $file =~ ^$f:\ ("C source"|"M3U playlist"|"exported SGML document") ]]; then
      echo rm -- "$f"
    fi
  done
' bash {} +
```

Remove the `echo` before `rm` if the output looks as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are in Bash, I would go this route:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$#" -ge 1 ] || { >&2 echo Supply at least one substring; exit 9; }
find . -type f -exec bash -c '
    terms=()
    nargs=$1
    shift
    for ((i=1;i<=nargs;i++)); do
        terms+=("-e")
        terms+=("$1")
        shift
    done
    for f; do
        if file -b -- "$f" | grep -Fq "${terms[@]}"; then
            echo rm -- "$f"
        fi
    done
' find-bash "$#" "$@" {} +
```

Save it as `script.bash`, make it executable with `chmod a+x script.bash`, and to run it:

```
./script.bash 'C source' 'M3U playlist' 'SGML'
```

The idea is to fill an array with the terms to be removed and then grep the `file` command output for each file.

The `-b` option, which suppresses the filename from `file`'s output, is used for `file` command so that the script does not break if the filename contains newlines.

Initially, the script only echoes what it would do. Once you are convinced there are no problems, remove the `echo` from the `rm` line. Some sample execution (notice the `A<newline>B` file):

```
$ file *
a b:                 empty
A
B:                 awk or perl script, ASCII text
Active.png:          PNG image data, 640 x 384, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
blanks.bash:         Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
covidActive.gnuplot: ASCII text
data.dat:            ASCII text
script.bash:         Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
table.txt:           ASCII text
test.sh:             POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

```
$ ./script.bash awk shell
rm -- ./script.bash
rm -- ./blanks.bash
rm -- ./test.sh
rm -- ./A
B
```

```
$ ls
'a b'   Active.png   covidActive.gnuplot   data.dat   table.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), a variation on [Freddy's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598287/315749):

```bsh
(
  types=( "C source" "M3U playlist" "exported SGML document" )
  IFS='|'
  shopt -s globstar dotglob
  for f in ./**; do
    if [[ $(file -b -- "$f") =~ ^(${types[*]}) ]]; then
      echo rm -- "$f"
    fi
  done
)
```

- A subshell (`( ... )`) is used to avoid changing `IFS` in the main environment.
- `IFS` is set to `|` to make the `${types[*]}` array expand to its members separated by a vertical bar (note the `*` subscript).
- `globstar` makes the `./**` glob match all files, directories and subdirectories (i.e. filename expansion descends recursively the tree rooted in the current working directory).
- `dotglob` makes `./**` also match hidden files.
- The `(${types[*]})` regular expression in the `[[` [compound command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b) expands to a `( )` group expression made of types separated by the `|` alternation symbol, anchored (`^`) to the beginning of the string to lower the chances of false positives. Note that this will likely not work if the members of `types` contain characters that are special in POSIX [Extended Regular Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (ERE).

Remove the `echo` when you are satisfied with the list of to-delete files.